# Animate the height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this stack of divs that changes z-index on click. When a new div gets the highest z-index being placed on top i want to animate the height of it. from 0 to 100p, so it looks like it "grows".

Anyone that can help on this?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfp17etg/2/

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="one current">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
<button>click</button>
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.holder {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
}

.holder div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}
.holder div.current{
    z-index:1;
}
.one {
   background:red;
}
.two {
    background:green;
}
.three {
    background: blue;
}
```

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    if ($(".holder >div:last-child").hasClass("current")) {
        $(".holder >div:last-child").removeClass("current");
        $(".holder >div:first-child").addClass("current");
    }
    else { 
        $(".current").removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
    }
});
```

Comment: You could just simulate the growth with `transform: scale(1.5 , 1.5)` or something - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: code added. thanks for the input. thats what I'm thinking of. just don't know how to apply it. i don't want it to scale tho. only animate the height.

Comment: Like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/muzikant1986/nfp17etg/3/

Comment: @AshotKhanamiryan. almost! the divs below need to be visible tho. so that it works almost as a mask.

Comment: I can't understant what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var div = $("div");
        div.animate({height: '300px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
        div.animate({width: '300px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
        div.animate({height: '100px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
        div.animate({width: '100px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
    });
});
```

[check jsFiddle demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/nfp17etg/4/)

Comment: hi, thanks!

this is almost what i want. i edited the fiddle a bit to explain my problem further. i want all divs below to be visible and have a height. its just the top one thats gonna animate from 0 to 100px.

http://jsfiddle.net/nfp17etg/5/

Comment: unfortunately i did not got it. still not there as you see in the fiddle provided.